how to hide/unhide android app icon in .net maui when app is completely closed and is not in background with Plugin.Firebase 3.0.0?
I want to hide android app when app is completely closed.When app is open it works but when app is closed doesn`t.I use firebase notification to reactivate app by sending notification(OnMessageRecieved).
It works when app is open but it dosen`t work when app is closed.It should work beacause I saw that in diffrent frameworks like android studio it works.But I want it to work with maui.This is my code:
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using Firebase.Messaging;
using Plugin.Firebase.CloudMessaging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Intent = Android.Content.Intent;

using Androidapp = Android.App.Application;
using static Android.Icu.Text.CaseMap;
using static Android.Provider.Settings;
using AnotherTestMaui;

namespace AnotherTestMaui.Platforms.Android
{

    [Service(Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]

    public class FireFire : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        Context a = null;
        public FireFire()
        {

        }
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            a = this;
        }
        public override void OnNewToken(string token)
        {

            base.OnNewToken(token);
            if (Preferences.ContainsKey("DeviceToken"))
            {
                Preferences.Remove("DeviceToken");
            }
            Preferences.Set("DeviceToken", token);

            


        }





        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            base.OnMessageReceived(message);

            PackageManager.SetComponentEnabledSetting(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.ComponentName,         ComponentEnabledState.Disabled, ComponentEnableOption.DontKillApp);
          



   
        }
        


    }
}````

